# Using pyqt5 to change a CircularGauge

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, qml, pyqt5

OK I've managed to make a CircularGauge load using PyQt5 and QML.  Here's my QML:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4
import QtQuick.Controls.Styles 1.4
import QtQuick.Extras 1.4
import QtQuick.Extras.Private 1.0

Rectangle {
     width: 300
     height: 300
     color: "#000000"

     CircularGauge {
          property real gauge_value: 10000.0
          anchors.centerIn: parent
          value: gauge_value
          maximumValue: 10000.0  // Largest Value
          minimumValue: 0.0       // Smallest Value
          style: CircularGaugeStyle {
               id: style
               tickmarkStepSize: 1000.0 // Tick Marks

               tickmark: Rectangle {
                    visible: styleData.value < 8000 || styleData.value % 1000 == 0
                    implicitWidth: outerRadius * 0.02
                    antialiasing: true
                    implicitHeight: outerRadius * 0.06
                    color: styleData.value >= 8000 ? "#ff0000" : "#ff0000"
               }

               minorTickmark: Rectangle {
                    visible: styleData.value < 8000
                    implicitWidth: outerRadius * 0.01
                    antialiasing: true
                    implicitHeight: outerRadius * 0.03
                    color: "#ff0000"
               }

               tickmarkLabel:  Text {
                    font.pixelSize: Math.max(6, outerRadius * 0.1)
                    text: styleData.value
                    color: styleData.value >= 8000 ? "#ff0000" : "#ff0000"
                    antialiasing: true
               }

               needle: Rectangle {
                    y: outerRadius * 0.15
                    implicitWidth: outerRadius * 0.03
                    implicitHeight: outerRadius * 1.1
                    antialiasing: true
                    color: "#ff0000"
               }

               foreground: Item {
                    Rectangle {
                         width: outerRadius * 0.2
                         height: width
                         radius: width / 2
                         color: "#b2b2b2"
                         anchors.centerIn: parent
                    }
               }
          }
     }
}
```

And now my Python script

```
import sys
import time
from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject, QUrl, Qt, pyqtProperty
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtQml import QQmlApplicationEngine, qmlRegisterType
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui
from PyQt5.QtQuick import QQuickView

if __name__ == "__main__":

     app = QApplication(sys.argv)
     view = QQuickView()
     view.setSource(QUrl('full_gauge.qml'))
     engine = view.engine()
     rot = 4000.0
     engine.rootContext().setContextProperty('gauge_value', rot)
     view.show()
     rot = 0.0
     engine.rootContext().setContextProperty('gauge_value', rot)
     view.update()
     view.show()
     sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Now what I get is this:

[image: Screen output]

Clearly my code is drawing the picture correctly but I'm not changing the value of the code.  From what I can tell from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39977266/change-value-property-of-circular-gauge) I may need to define a class?  Sorry still a bit of a Python Newbie.  What would be really great is if I could get the gauge cycle through various values.

Update:
So from that other post I see I need to make a class:

```
 class Tachometer(QObject):
      def __init__(self, parent=None):
           super().__init__(parent)
           # Initialise the value of the properties.
           self._rpm_value = rpm_value

      # Define the getter of the 'rpm_value' property.  The C++ type and
      # Python type of the property is float.
      @pyqtProperty(float)
      def rpm_value(self):
           print("Getting value")
           return self._rpm_value

      # Define the setter of the 'rpm_value' property.
      @rpm_value.setter
      def rpm_value(self, value):
           print("Setting value")
           self._rpm_value = value
```

Now somehow I need to link this to my QML.  However, here I'm getting confused.  First do I need to add this to my QML?  Second, how do I tie this into my code, my best attempt is:

```
 if __name__ == "__main__":
      # Create the application instance
      app = QApplication(sys.argv)
      # Register the Python type.  Its URI is 'Tachometer', it's v1.0 and the type
      # will be called 'Tachometer' in QML.
      qmlRegisterType(Tachometer, 'Tachometer', 1, 0, 'Tachometer')
      # Create a QML engine.
      view = QQuickView()
      engine = view.engine()
      # Create a component factory and load the QML script.
      component = QQmlComponent(engine)
      #component.loadUrl(QUrl('full_gauge.qml'))
      view.setSource(QUrl('full_gauge.qml'))
      # draw the window
      view.show()
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: You change `gauge_value` property of *root* item. In your case that is `Rectangle` which has no such property. You have to use [view.findChild](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#findChild) to find `CircularGauge` item. Don't forget to add `objectName` property. And don't call `view.show()` several times, it doesn't make sense here.

Comment: You need to set `gauge_value` before you load the QML.
However, if you want to update the value from Python, I would recommend to expose an object instead of a value and let that object have a property that holds the value. That way you can just bind to that property in QML and it updates automatically whenever you change it in Python

Comment: Ah, the post you linked to is already describing the better solution. You might have to combine that with the "notify" part of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28517132/i-want-to-set-a-qt-qml-combobox-to-a-pyqt5-object-property/34974323#34974323) solution.

Comment: So I've tried following that post but part of the problem is that the full code isn't uploaded so there are missing parts.  I can define the class QObject but how do I connect my class (call it "Tachometer") to the QML?  Thanks.

Comment: You need no additional class until you really need that. Always use Occam's razor. Did you try my comment above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I figured out how to change the value.  One issue was a typo, but otherwise this appears to work.

QML

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4
import QtQuick.Controls.Styles 1.4
import QtQuick.Extras 1.4
import QtQuick.Extras.Private 1.0

Rectangle {
    width: 300
    height: 300
    color: "#000000"

    CircularGauge {
        objectName: "test_gauge"
        property real gauge_value: 10000.0
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        value: gauge_value
        maximumValue: 10000.0  // Largest Value
        minimumValue: 0.0       // Smallest Value
        style: CircularGaugeStyle {
            id: style
            tickmarkStepSize: 1000.0 // Tick Marks

            tickmark: Rectangle {
                visible: styleData.value < 8000 || styleData.value % 1000 == 0
                implicitWidth: outerRadius * 0.02
                antialiasing: true
                implicitHeight: outerRadius * 0.06
                color: styleData.value >= 8000 ? "#ff0000" : "#ff0000"
            }

           minorTickmark: Rectangle {
                visible: styleData.value < 8000
                implicitWidth: outerRadius * 0.01
                antialiasing: true
                implicitHeight: outerRadius * 0.03
                color: "#ff0000"
           }

           tickmarkLabel:  Text {
                font.pixelSize: Math.max(6, outerRadius * 0.1)
                text: styleData.value
                color: styleData.value >= 8000 ? "#ff0000" : "#ff0000"
                antialiasing: true
           }

           needle: Rectangle {
                y: outerRadius * 0.15
                implicitWidth: outerRadius * 0.03
                implicitHeight: outerRadius * 1.1
                antialiasing: true
                color: "#ff0000"
           }

           foreground: Item {
                Rectangle {
                     width: outerRadius * 0.2
                     height: width
                     radius: width / 2
                     color: "#b2b2b2"
                     anchors.centerIn: parent
                }
           }
      }
 }
}
```

Python

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys
import time
from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject, QUrl, Qt, pyqtProperty, pyqtSignal
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtQml import QQmlApplicationEngine, qmlRegisterType, QQmlEngine, QQmlComponent
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui
from PyQt5.QtQuick import QQuickView

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    view = QQuickView()
    view.setSource(QUrl('full_gauge.qml'))
    gauge=view.findChild(QObject,'test_gauge')
    gauge.setProperty('gauge_value',4500)
    view.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Now I can set the 'value' of the gauge.

[image: Image showing it works.]

Answer (score 1):

Ok, as I already said, you are changing property of a wrong item. Actually, you are trying to change property `gauge_value` of black rectangle witch in fact is root item and have no such property at all.

I don't know how to do that in Python but in C++ I would do that:

```
QObject *root = dynamic_cast<QObject *>(engine.rootObjects().first());
QObject *gauge = root->findChild<QObject *>("gauge");
gauge->setProperty("gauge_value",5000);
```

Of cource your `CircularGauge` should look like this:

```
CircularGauge {
    objectName: "gauge" // << add this
    property real gauge_value: 10000.0
    // the code here
}
```

Comment: This makes sense but I'm having trouble implementing it in Python.  First I define my view `view = QQuickView()` then I get the engine object `engine = view.engine()` and then I attempt to get first object `root = engine.rootObjects().first()`.  But here is where the code crashes.  I get a message saying that the QQmlEngine object has no attribute rootObjects.